# Comparing two distributions with different biased sampling criteria

Tags: sampling, bias

Suppose you are running an experiment with two conditions, `A` and `B`.
At the beginning of the experiment, both populations are the same, and of equal size. After a (teaching) intervention, both groups receive a post-test. Then the students that succeed on the post-test come back later and do a review, (the reviews are identical), which they either pass or fail.

The post test and the review are similar, so a student might fail the post test but would have passed the review if they had seen it - perhaps they slipped up, perhaps they learned in the intervening time. However, if they miss the post-test they won't get a chance for review.

Now, suppose that condition `A` people pass the post-test more often, without necessarily learning more long-term (maybe they did, maybe they didn't). Now more participants from condition `A` will be doing the review. However, on average, they'll perform worse because it was easier to pass the post-test in condition `A`. So the absolute number of people to pass review in condition `A` is higher than in condition `B`, but the relative increase in people passing is lower than the relative increase in people failing.

For instance, let's say the numbers are:
$$\begin{array}{c|cc}&{\rm Group\ A}&{\rm Group\ B}\\\hline
{\rm To\ begin}&{\rm 100\ people}&{\rm 100\ people}\\
\text{Passing post-test}&{\rm 60\ people}&{\rm 40\ people}\\
{\rm Passing\ review}&{\rm 40\ people}&{\rm 30\ people}\end{array}$$

How can I tell what intervention was more effective at teaching, if 75% of the people I sample from condition `B` pass, but only 60% of the people from condition `A`, when there was also a sampling bias causing the condition `B` people to be higher caliber?

It's worth noting that I have hundreds of thousands of samples, and additional demographic information about the samples.

Comment: Do you assume that everyone who would fail both post tests would fail the review?  Also is the review the same for both A and B? Did any students who failed either post test take the review?

Comment: The post test and the review are similar, so a student might fail the post test but would have passed the review if they had seen it - perhaps they slipped up, perhaps they learned in the intervening time. However, if they miss the post-test they won't get a chance for review. And yes, the review is the same for A and B.

Comment: I think there are two confounded effects with this design, being the group differences and the relative difficulties of the post-test.

Comment: The relative difficulties of the post test *causes* the group differences; the initial distributions are the same and then the post test differentiates. The design is a side effect of the process that generates the data, which is designed for teaching, not for optimal scientific validity.